AspectJ @Pointcut and @AfterReturning based on method annotation not being triggered
I have other ways to accomplish this, but I've never done any AspectJ so I'm trying such an approach.
I want to annotate various getters such that their results are always cast to lowercase:
@AlwaysLower
@JsonProperty("clinic_id")
public String getClinicId() {
    return clinicId;
}

I have the annotation defined as such:
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface AlwaysLower {
}

And here's my @Aspect class:
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class AlwaysLowerAspect {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AlwaysLowerAspect.class);
    
    public AlwaysLowerAspect() {
        super();
        LOG.info("AlwaysLowerAspect constructed!");
    }

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.mycompany.mypackage.AlwaysLower)")
    public void annotatedWithAlwaysLower() {}

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "annotatedWithAlwaysLower()", returning = "returnValue")
    public void convertToLowercase(Object returnValue) {
        if (returnValue instanceof String) {
            String original = (String) returnValue;
            if (original != null) {
                returnValue = original.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }
}

At runtime, I see the constructor fire, but neither of the annotated methods within my @Aspect are triggered.  I am using a fake package name, here, but the correct one is in my code and I'm getting nothing.  Am I trying to accomplish the impossible, and/or what am I doing wrong?

An aspect is a@Component, not a @Configuration.

Please also note that you should always provide an MCVE. Especially here in this case, the problems could also hide in parts of the code you are hiding from the community here. E.g., I cannot find out if the class containing the getClinicId() method is properly registered as a Spring bean, which is essential if you wish to use Spring AOP. If that was not the case, you would have to use native AspectJ.
